# implementing future::then() equivalent for asynchronous execution in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a few questions about the implementation of the function `then()` in [Herb Sutter's talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism). This function is used to chain asynchronous operations, the parameter `f` is a future from one operation and the parameter `w` is the 'work' for this operation (lambda).

```
template <typename Fut, typename Work>
auto then(Fut f, Work w) -> future<decltype(w(f.get()))>
{
    return async([=]{ w(f.get()); });
}
```

An example of application would be:

```
    std::future<int> f = std::async([]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(200));
        return 10;
    });

    auto f2 = then(std::move(f), [](int i){
        return 2 * i;
    });
```

The main thread spawns the tasks but does not wait for any of them to finish.

Firstly, `future<T>` does not have a copy constructor. This means, that the suggested implementation can be only used with `shared_future<T>` unless we change the call to `async()` to move the future into the lambda. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200678/c11-async-continuations-or-attempt-at-then-semantics/14200861#comment20089049_14200861) suggested a way of doing it but it seems too complicated. I re-implemented the function and I am wondering whether my code is correct or whether I missed something...

Secondly, the future that is passed to the `then()` function might be `void` so we actually need 2 implementations of `then()`, right? One for futures returning `T` and one for futures returning `void`.

Lastly, should the lambda inside the body of `then()` not have a return statement so that we can actually return the value back? Without the return statement, then returns `future<void>`, right?

I tried to address the above points and this is what I came up with. Is it correct?

```
template <typename T, typename Work>
auto then(future<T> f, Work w) -> future<decltype(w(f.get()))>
{
    return async([](future<T> f, Work w)
                      { return w(f.get()); }, move(f), move(w));
}

template <typename Work>
auto then(future<void> f, Work w) -> future<decltype(w())>
{
    return async([](future<void> f, Work w)
                      { f.wait(); return w(); }, move(f), move(w));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"

Comment: By "correct" I mean logically correct. The code compiles fine (clang 3.3 + libc++) but that does not mean it does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: No, you do not need another version because of void - it is perfectly fine to do something like this: `void f(); void g() { return f(); }`.

Comment: The problem is not the `return f();` part but the `w(f.get())` part. You are trying to pass a `void` parameter to a function that does not take any parameters. E.g., `void f(); void g(); [](){ return f(g()); }`

Comment: There is no such thing as a void parameter. It's a keyword that represent *not* a parameter.

Comment: My point exactly. That is the reason for the second version of `then()`.

Comment: I'd write a `future`->functor adapter, and a `chain` function that handles the `void` return value, rather than writing two `then`.

Comment: Is it maybe interesting to have a look of the implementation of [` then` in boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures)?

Comment: Working link to [Herb Sutter's talk](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321021750/http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism).

Answer (score 6):

The problem with this approach to .then() is that you spawn 2 threads (that is costly) simultaneously, and second of them would block on its future.get/wait (if the first one would run long enough, of course)
So, its better to use the work queue, to serialize the jobs execution order (and re-cycle the existing threads). 
Just look for a good Thread pool pattern implementation

Comment: Any recommendations for one?

Comment: @dromodel there are many of them, just google for c++ thread pool implementations)

Answer (score 4):

In order to simplify the interface, I would "hide" the `void` problem inside the implementation, similarly to what Herb did with his `concurrent<T>` implementation. Instead of having 2 `then` implementations, declare a helper function `get_work_done` with 2 implementations:

```
template <typename T, typename Work>
auto get_work_done(future<T> &f, Work &w)-> decltype(w(f.get()))
{return w(f.get());}

template <typename Work>
auto get_work_done(future<void> &f, Work &w)-> decltype(w())
{f.wait(); return w();}
```

And then let template parameter detection take care of the rest:

```
template <typename T, typename Work>
auto then(future<T> f, Work w) -> future<decltype(w(f.get()))>
{
    return async([](future<T> f, Work w)
                      { return get_work_done(f,w); }, move(f), move(w));
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this adds any value. I guess if there was more work in the ``then`` function it would make sense but as it is there is no need for the extra function.

Comment: The idea is simplifying the interface and leaving the implementation details "inside". But since it's just 2 overloads, and very short code it's not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

no, it is not correct. if you pass return value of .get() to continuation, it will not be able to handle exception, propagated from .get(). you have to pass future to continuation, and call .get() manually, just like in boost.thread

Comment: No, if `.get()` throws from inside the new lambda, the future created from *that* will correctly hold that exception.

Comment: no, this will handle exception at the end of chain, skipping all steps in between, while without .then() you can handle exceptions after every step

Comment: Eh, that's the whole idea behind `.then` - *if* the work was successful, *then* do some other work. You might argue that it would be good to be able to pass an "else" function, so you can handle exceptions too, and I won't argue against that.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the idea is to do some work after previous step is finished either by return or by exception. just like in sequential code without .then().
i argue that it would be good to have a chance to handle exception in continuation ( for example by substituting default value instead of result of .get() ).
also i predict you will have some fun implementing .else()

Comment: C++14: f1.then([](future f) { return f.get().to_string(); // here .get() won’t block }); 
Otherwise there is no way to capture the error