# Creating a future from intermediate futures?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following sample code I want to create an `Item` object from a `Component`:

```
struct Component { };

struct Item {
    explicit Item(Component component) : comp(component) {}    
    Component comp;
};

struct Factory {
    static std::future<Item> get_item() {
        std::future<Component> component = get_component();        
        // how to get a std::future<Item> ?
    }

    std::future<Component> get_component();
};
```

How do I go from `std::future<Component>` to `std::future<Item>`?

**Update:** removed my first idea (which was thread-based) from the question and posted an answer.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: A side note- better use a const ref in the constructor of Item.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how is it review question? . He is looking for better approach/way!

Comment: @M3taSpl0it that's the point of Code Review.

Comment: @Zoidberg But don't you think it will be better answered here rather than there?

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: And you define code review as....?

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: That is irrelevant. I could probably get a better answer to "how should I make a good bong" here than on scifi.stackexchange.com, but that doesn't make it on-topic ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right :)

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: Typically so ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurred to me that I can use `std::async` with the *deferred* launch policy to compose the final object:

```
std::future<Item> get_item()
{
    // start async creation of component
    // (using shared_future to make it copyable)
    std::shared_future<Component> component = get_component();

    // deferred launch policy can be used for construction of the final object
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, [=]() {
        return Item(component.get());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. I needed a way to effectively construct a `std::future` object, but the use of threads would have been completely unnecessary.

Comment: Why is it using `shared_future`? Couldn't it use `future` and move from it instead of copying?

Comment: @Xeverous yeah, that would be better

Comment: I find this solution unusable - it is impossible to check whether `get_item()` is ready. Whenever you ask it to `wait_for` with zero time to check if it's ready it will return that it is deferred and never start `get_component()`. If you start it explicitly by `.get()` then you have a blocking call and there is no asynchronous code at all.

Answer (score 13):

Needs moar packaged_tasks!

```
std::future<Item> get_item() {
    std::packaged_task<Item()> task([]{
        return Item(get_component().get());
    });
    auto future = task.get_future();
    std::thread(std::move(task)).detach();
    return future;
};
```

In general I recommend forgetting about promises and considering packaged_tasks first. A `packaged_task` takes care of maintaining a (function, promise, future) triple for you. It lets you write the function in a natural way (i.e. with returns and throws and so on), and propagates the exceptions correctly into the future, which your example neglected (unhandled exceptions in *any* thread `std::terminate` your program!).

Comment: Isn't there a better way? I am wondering why is there another thread needed if all the user is trying is to hide some internal implementation and expose a better interface.

Comment: @balki not with standard stuff. There are plans to add `future.then()`, and that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `then` function proposed by Herb Sutter. Here is a slightly modified version of the function. More information about how it was modified and a link to the original talk can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489935/implementing-futurethen-equivalent-for-asynchronous-execution-in-c11). Your code would boil down to:

```
return then(std::move(component), [](Component c) { return Item(c); });
```

The original idea is to have the function `then` as a member function of `std::future<T>` and there is some ongoing work of putting it into the standard. The second version of the function is for `void` futures (essentially just chaining functions asynchronously). As Herb pointed out, you might pay for using this approach by potentially needing an extra thread.

Your code would look like this:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T, typename Work>
auto then(std::future<T> f, Work w) -> std::future<decltype(w(f.get()))>
{
  return std::async([](std::future<T> f, Work w)
                    { return w(f.get()); }, std::move(f), std::move(w));
}

template <typename Work>
auto then(std::future<void> f, Work w) -> std::future<decltype(w())>
{
  return std::async([](std::future<void> f, Work w) -> decltype(w())
                    { f.wait(); return w(); }, std::move(f), std::move(w));
}

struct Component { };

struct Item {
  Item(Component component) : comp(component) {}
  Component comp;
};


struct Factory {
  static std::future<Item> get_item() {
    std::future<Component> component = get_component();
    return then(std::move(component), [](Component c) { return Item(c); });
  }

  static std::future<Component> get_component()
  {
    return std::async([](){ return Component(); });
  }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto f = Factory::get_item();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine with clang and libc++ (tested on Mac OS X 10.8).