# C++20 coroutines: implementing an awaitable future

Tags: c++, async-await, future, c++20, c++-coroutine

Since the Coroutines TS has been accepted into C++20 at the ISO meeting at Kona, I started playing around with them a bit for myself. Clang already has decent support for coroutines but the implementation of the library support is still lacking. In particular, the *Awaitable* types such as `std::future`, `std::generator`, etc. have not been implemented yet.

Thus, I took it upon myself to make `std::future` awaitable. I largely followed the [talk by James McNellis at CppCon 2016](https://youtu.be/ZTqHjjm86Bw?t=2261), specifically this slide:

[image: Screengrab at timestamp 37:41 of James McNellis talk at CppCon 2016]

This being 2019, I actually had some trouble with the (presumably untested?) code on this slide:

- It seems to me overloading `operator co_await` is not a thing anymore? Instead one should use the optional `await_transform` of the `promise_type`. Not sure I got this right, though.
- The `then` continuation of the future captures the handle by value, but the `resume` member function is not const-qualified. I worked around this by making the lambda `mutable`.

Also, `then` and `is_ready` are not available in `std::future` but are part of [`std::experimental::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future) which is still missing from my libc++ version. To avoid dealing with the Awaiter and to implement future continuations, I wrote a derived future class which is Awaitable and an Awaiter. It is my understanding that eventually both would also be true of `std::future`. You can see my [example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/iUR8vn). It *does* compile.

However, it also *does* segfault. This happens in `await_resume` when `get()` is called. This is actually not surprising since `valid()` returns `false` at that point (making the call to `get()` UB). I think this is because when `then` is used to continue the future, the original future object is moved into the async future, thus invalidating the old future (`*this` at the time `await_resume` is called, so after the move). My implementation of `then` is loosely inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935704/2788450) and [this code](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/then) I found on GitHub. Those may not be ideal, but [cppreference explicitly states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then) `valid() == false` as a postcondition of calling `then`, so I believe it is correct to move out of the original future.

What am I missing here? This "bug" seems present already in the above slide. How can I reconcile this issue? Does anybody know of a (working) existing implementation of an Awaitable future? Thanks.

Comment: "*Since the Coroutines TS has been accepted into C++20 at the ISO meeting at Kona*" It should be noted that the Coroutines TS is not exactly what was adopted into C++20. The C++20 coroutines feature is *similar* to the Coroutines TS, but not 1:1 identical.

Comment: "Does anybody know of a (working) existing implementation of an Awaitable future?"  https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro.  Note that the author also has a blog with explanations e.g. https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70406948/5447906) is how `std::future` can be made awaitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, the issue is because the `future` has moved-from after calling `.then()`. The trick is to move it back when it's ready. This can be done if the continuation passed to `.then()` takes the `future`, not the value it holds.

Here are the functions I took from your code and changed. I also changed them from passing things to `std::async` as parameters to just capturing them, as this looks more intuitive to me, but this isn't the important change here.

```cpp
    template <typename Work>
    auto then(Work&& w) -> co_future<decltype(w())> {
        return { std::async([fut = std::move(*this), w = std::forward<Work>(w)]() mutable {
            fut.wait();
            return w();
        })};
    }

    template <typename Work>
    auto then(Work&& w) -> co_future<decltype(w(std::move(*this)))> {
        return { std::async([fut = std::move(*this), w = std::forward<Work>(w)]() mutable {
            return w(std::move(fut));
        })};
    }

    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> ch) {
        then([ch, this](auto fut) mutable {
            *this = std::move(fut);
            ch.resume();
        });
    }
```

BTW, VS2017 complains about having both `set_exception()` and `unhandled_exception()` in the promise type. I removed `set_exception()` and changed `unhandled_exception()` to this:

```cpp
    void unhandled_exception() {
        _promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
```