# Can coroutine return std::future? (unable to find the promise type for this coroutine)

Tags: c++, future, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have tried to compile coroutine example from the CppCon presentation https://youtu.be/ZTqHjjm86Bw?t=560

[image]

Unfortunately compilation fails:

```
$ g++-10 -pedantic -Wall -std=c++20 -fcoroutines main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘std::future<int> compute_value()’:
main.cpp:7:16: error: unable to find the promise type for this coroutine
    7 |   int result = co_await std::async([]
      |                ^~~~~~~~
```

At the beginning presenter warns that what he is about to present is just a proposal. So it makes me confused: can `std::future` be return from a coroutine, or do I just try to call it incorrectly?

Full code:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

std::future<int> compute_value(){
  int result = co_await std::async([] 
  {
    return 30;
  });

  co_return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << compute_value().get() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are (basically<sup>1</sup>) no standard library types in C++20 that implement the necessary coroutine machinery to make coroutines work. This *includes* `std::promise<T>/future<T>`.

You could write wrappers for them that implement the coroutine machinery though.

<sup>1</sup>: There are [support types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine) like `std::suspend_always/never` which have coroutine machinery, but they don't really do anything like what you're thinking of.

Comment: The coroutine *machinery* and the standard library *support* are going in in two pieces I believe, so one doesn't block the other.

Comment: so in the future I will be able to return std::future from a coroutine?

Comment: @user2449761: Maybe. They might use a different type specific to this use case.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because of the mention of `std::promise<T>/future<T>`. These are meant for multithreading and have nothing to do with coroutines.

Comment: @BartLouwers: The question is asking about if coroutines work with `std::future`. How can I answer a question about the capabilities of `std::future` without mentioning `std::future`? Also, saying that coroutines "have nothing to do with" multithreading is rather inaccurate, since asynchronous resumption of coroutines is the *primary* design goal of the feature.

Comment: Are there any such standard library types in C++23, or C++26? Can the OP's code work without modification then?

Comment: @user2023370: There have been noises made about giving `std::future` continuation powers, but nothing has actually come of it. It's simply the wrong type for doing this, as continuations require some knowledge of *how* the async process works and whether that process itself has hooks for continuations. And `future` knows nothing of that. It'd be better to have a higher-level type that knows more about the process generating a value besides a `promise`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 a user should manually enable the use of `std::future<T>` as a coroutine type. A minimal complete example for `std::future<int>`:

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

template <>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::future<int>> {
  struct promise_type : std::promise<int> {
    std::future<int> get_return_object() { return this->get_future(); }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_value(int value) { this->set_value(value); }
    void unhandled_exception() {
      this->set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
  };
};

auto operator co_await(std::future<int> future) {
  struct awaiter : std::future<int> {
    bool await_ready() { return false; } // suspend always
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
      std::thread([this, handle]() {
        this->wait();
        handle.resume();
      }).detach();
    }
    int await_resume() { return this->get(); }
  };
  return awaiter{std::move(future)};
}

std::future<int> compute_value() {
  int result = co_await std::async([] { return 30; });

  co_return result;
}

int main() { std::cout << compute_value().get() << std::endl; }
```

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_traits

Comment: It’s not permitted to specialize standard library templates strictly for other standard library types like that, though.

Comment: @DavisHerring, specializing `std::coroutine_traits` is permitted. It was created specifically for user specializations.

Comment: @anton_rh: Of course you can specialize it, but it must be for a _program-defined_ type.

Comment: @DavisHerring, ok, I understand. You are right.

Comment: The problem may be worked around by making user-defined type `Future` that is derived from `std::future` and using it instead of `std::future`.

Comment: This implementation is spawning a thread to wait synchronously on the `std::future`, which negates the benefit of using coroutines.