# Can C++ coroutines contain plain `return` statements?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt, c++-coroutine, cppwinrt

I am writing a C++ coroutine for a UWP control using [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt):

```cpp
winrt::fire_and_forget MyControl::DoSomething()
{
    if (/* some condition */)
    {
         // Why does this work?!
         return;
    }

    co_await winrt::resume_foreground(Dispatcher());

    // Do some stuff

    co_return;
}
```

This is compiling for me, but as far as I know, C++ coroutines do not allow plain `return` statements. Is this a bug in the compiler?

(Interestingly, I cannot change the `co_return` to `return`; I get a compiler error. Is it that only return statements *after* a `co_await` or `co_yield` must be `co_return`?)

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a legacy implementation for MSVSC. MSVSC implemented coroutines before the standard was formally complete, so [there are two implementations of async](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-coroutines-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-8/) (`/async` and `/async:strict`). I seem to have the old, non–standard-compliant version turned on.

The standard is clear that **you cannot use plain `return` statements in coroutines** (emphasis added):

> Coroutines cannot use variadic arguments, **plain return statements**, or placeholder return types (auto or Concept). Constexpr functions, constructors, destructors, and the main function cannot be coroutines.

— https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

You can verify that this is a legacy behavior with a simple example ([view in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W136ceh1r)):

```cpp
// ... boilerplate to make std::futures awaitable ...
// via https://stackoverflow.com/a/70406948/788168

std::future<int> compute_value()
{
    if (rand() > 5)
    {
        // Shouldn't work:
        return 5;
    }

    int result = co_await std::async([] { return 30; });

    co_return result;
}

int main() {
    compute_value();
}
```

With the `x64 msvc v19.latest` compiler and the `/std:c++20` flag, we get this error:

```
example.cpp
<source>(38): error C3773: Use of 'return' in this context is a non-conforming extension in C++20
<source>(38): note: Please use '/await' command-line option to enable relevant extensions
Compiler returned: 2
```

---

So, to answer the questions:

> This is compiling for me, but as far as I know, C++ coroutines do not allow plain `return` statements. Is this a bug in the compiler?
>
> (Interestingly, I cannot change the `co_return` to `return`; I get a compiler error. Is it that only return statements *after* a `co_await` or `co_yield` must be `co_return`?)

It's not a bug in the compiler, it's just a non-standard implementation. If you use the standard implementation (with `/async:strict` or `/std:c++20`), that plain `return` statement will not compile. Standards-compliant coroutines **cannot** use plain return statements, ever.